# Entity framework in MVC 4 - Include returning false result

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, include

I have two tables:

**Products:**
ProductID, ProductName

**Compounds:**

CompoundID, ComponentID, Qty

bound as next:

1 Products.**ProductID** --> many Compounds.**CompoundID**

1 Products.**ProductID** --> many Compounds.**ComponentID**

A Products item can be a compound, a components, or both.

I need that a view returns for each compound its components names and Quatities.

MyController method :

```
public ActionResult CompoundProduct()
    {
        var Compounds = db.Compounds.Include(s => s.Products);
        return View(Compounds.ToList());
    }
```

MyView code :
    @model IEnumerable

```
<table>
@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CompoundID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ComponentID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Products.ProductName)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

With this method I get a list of repeated Compound name instead of distinct Component names per Compound as shown in the image below:
[image]

any help please ?

Comment: Where are you getting the Compound name?

Comment: Both Compound and component names are From the Product table **ProductName field**.

Comment: Could you show the entity classes and the mapping?

Comment: Don't you have **two** navigation properties with name `ProductXXX` in your `Compound` entity? You apparently have **two** foreign keys (`CompoundID` and `ComponentID`) from the `Compounds` to the `Products` table, so you should have **two** properties. The one you are using in `Include` is probably related to `CompoundId`, but you need the one related to `ComponentId`.

Comment: @Slauma, that's right I have two navigation properties: Products and Products1, but in spite of using Products1 I still get the same result.

Comment: Could you show some sample data (row values in `Compounds` and `Products` table) where this happens with?

Comment: @Slauma, Updated the question with the requested data.

Comment: I actually meant the database tables, not the view. But just another question: You said that `Products1` would yield the same result. When you tested with `Products1` did you use `Products1` in the `Include` **AND** in the view (`@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Products1.ProductName`)?

Comment: Yes of course, that's it, I had to use also Products1 also in the view like this: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Products1.ProductName), please make your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you created the model from the database EF should have created **two** navigation properties `Products` and `Products1` related to the two foreign keys `CompoundID` and `ComponentID`. You are probably using the wrong navigation property that belongs to `CompoundID`, not the one that belongs to `ComponentID`. Instead of `Products` try to use `Products1` in the `Include`...

```
var Compounds = db.Compounds.Include(s => s.Products1);
```

...and in the view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Products1.ProductName)
```